# Show interstitial ads by calling method from different class? (StartApp)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, interstitial, startapp

So because I try to monetize game it's a bit more difficult since there is no "`public void onCreate`" method in java class in which I need to call ads. Adding a banner is no issue for me but it's interstitial ads I can't call. In my main java class I created a method:

```
public void showInter(){
        startAppAd.showAd();
        startAppAd.loadAd();
    }
```

So in other class I made "`MainClass example = new MainClass();`" and when game ends I call "`example.showInter()`" but ads don't show. Anyone has idea for solution? I can't create `StartAppAd` object in this class in the normal way at least.

Comment: Shouldn't load be before show?

Comment: No it's in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

Did you init startAppAd before using it?

```
private StartAppAd startAppAd = new StartAppAd(this);
```

You can also use AdEventListener to get a callback for loading the ad and check why the ads are failing:
https://github.com/StartApp-SDK/Documentation/wiki/android-advanced-usage#adding-a-callback-when-an-interstitial-ad-is-loaded